How do I do a OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict) on a Many to Many relationship in EF Core 8?
I have a class called Language:
public class Language : ValueObject
{
    private List<LanguageType> _typesOfLanguage;

    public IEnumerable<LanguageType> TypesOfLanguage => _typesOfLanguage.AsReadOnly();
}

My entity type configuration is:
    public class LanguageEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Language>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Language> configuration)
        {
            configuration.HasMany(lang => lang.TypesOfLanguage)
                         .WithMany()
                         .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
         }
     }

I cannot build because the OnDelete() is causing the following issue:

CollectionCollectionBuilder<LanguageType, Language> does not contain a definition for "OnDelete" and no extensible extension method 'OnDelete' accepting a first argument of type 'CollectionCollectionBuilder<LanguageType, Language>' could be found

How can I restrict delete on a many-to-many relationship?

Are you sure you have set up all the entities you need for a many-to-many relationship? I see a language class, but no language types class and no class such as LanguageLanguageType (the joining entity).  Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many#examples Also BTW it seems that the "restrict" behavior is the same as the default behavior so you could leave out that line and see what happens). Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.deletebehavior?view=efcore-8.0

@topsail I need a Many to Many but it is unidirectional.

"But it is unidirectional" ... what does that mean?

As can be read in the docs, this method exists on type ReferenceCollectionBuilder, not on CollectionCollectionBuilder<,>.
You need to create foreign key relation in order to specify action on delete.
You can do it by defining custom junction entity (see junction table like below:
public class StudentClass
{
    public Guid StudentId { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }
    public Guid ClassId { get; set; }
    public Class Class { get; set; }
}

public class Class
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<StudentClass> StudentClasses { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<StudentClass> StudentClasses { get; set; }
}

public class ConsoleContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Class> Classes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StudentClass> StudentClasses { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<StudentClass>()
            .HasKey(x => new { x.StudentId, x.ClassId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<StudentClass>()
            .HasOne(c => c.Student)
            .WithMany(x => x.StudentClasses)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        modelBuilder.Entity<StudentClass>()
            .HasOne(c => c.Class)
            .WithMany(x => x.StudentClasses)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}


You have a One to Many I believe.  StudentClass HasOne Student.

@MikeLenart Yes, Student has one StudentClass - this is junciton entity
